# Visual Studio Code 2017 and Gulp - tasks show, but arent running?

Tags: node.js, gulp, visual-studio-code

Trying to get gulp running with a test site in Visual Studio Code 2017.  Here is a rundown of what I have done so far :

- created a workspace
- node command prompt 'npm install --global gulp'
- cd to workspace folder and 'init npm'
- npm install gulp --save-dev
- npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
- npm install gulp-uglify --save-dev
- npm install gulp-imagemin --save-dev
- npm install gulp-watch --save-dev

Created a gulpfile.js in the root of the workspace with the following :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('_config/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('_config/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('_config/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('img', function () {
    return gulp.src('_config/img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('_config/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('_config/js/**/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch('_config/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('_config/img/**/*', ['img']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'js', 'scripts', 'img']);
```

Now, I should be able to create a .scss file in _config/scss/ and it will go ahead and create the min css version in /assets/css/, but this is not happening.  If I hit `ctl-shift-p' and go to 'run tasks' I see that the tasks are detected, but that would be for running manually.  What do I need to do for this to start auto when I open the workspace... in which case my watch tasks would be running as they should?

I found some stuff about a tasks.json file specifically for VS Code, but couldn't find a whole lot of information about that and what it should consist of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `'gulp'` in your terminal (without the quotes) and it will start the `'default'` task which starts all your other tasks.

However, you do not presently have the `'watch'` task started automatically so add it to the `'default'` task:

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'js', 'scripts', 'img', 'watch']);
```

When you want to end this task press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.

[There are probably ways to have the gulp default task start automatically when you open the workspace but first things first - get this working first.]

[Plus, there is no such thing as Visual Studio Code 2017.]